# Using a batch file to create a text file that gives me a list of all folders and subfolders

Tags: batch-file

Don't know much about programming. After a good 45 minutes of searching online and finding how to do this with only folders and not subfolders, I have decided to come here.

I have done the part where you open Text program and type:

dir /b > fileslist.txt

And then save it as:

filelist.bat

And then place that .bat file in the folder that I want to create a list from.

Though this gives me a list of just the folders in there but not the folders within the folders. And I don't want the files that are in there. Just folders and subfolders.

I am using Windows 7 and the folder I am in is Libraries\Pictures

Within Pictures, I have about 75 folders broken down by activities and trips, etc. And within some of those folders, I have subfolders related to specific activities and trips.

I would love to have this as a text file for quick reference so I can keep it in my email. When I'm not at home, I can quickly open this text file from my email and tell my gf which folder the certain picture she is looking for is in.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `dir /S /A:D /B > fileslist.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /s
```

will list files recursively (in all subdirectories).

You can see all options with

```
dir /?
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following command to only see directories and print all directories:

```
dir /s /a:d /b > fileslist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tree >> out.txt    # (this will give you the directories / sub directories structure)

dir /s >> out.txt  # (this will give you a list)
```

Note that `>` is for overwriting and `>>` is for appending...